# Does the phrase '(very) lazy to do something' make sense?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, grammaticality

We have a common pattern 'too lazy to do something'. Apart from this pattern, can we use the word 'lazy' with the to-infinitive. I have looked it up in many dictionaries but have not found any examples. If the phrase '(very) lazy to do something' does not make sense, what could be an  alternative to express the idea behind this phrase?

Comment: Does this answer help? https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/304274/in-sentences-with-too-and-enough-what-word-does-the-to-infinitive-modify

Comment: "Too lazy to do something" means you are unable to do something. There are other phrases which mean you are reluctant to do something but you may do it eventually or half-heartedly, e.g. "very lazy about doing something". What meaning do you want, and why don't you want "too lazy to do something". (The above link explains the grammar of "too X to Y".)

Comment: @StuartF I understand that the phrase with 'too' has a negative meaning. My question is about grammaticality of the pattern/phrase '(very) lazy to do something'. I think it is incorrect but I am not very sure.

Comment: _Lazy_ does not take an infinitive complement, so *_He is (very) lazy to do something_ is ungrammatical. On the other hand, the negative construction _He is too lazy to do something_ is fine; the negative construction _too X to VP_ means so X that not VP.

Answer (score 0):

Unmotivated/ unmoved/ in no rush/ under no pressure/ without care/ without regard/ to do something are other ways to express it. Very lazy to do something sounds foreign. In what context is it being used? Too lazy to do what? If there was more context perhaps I could suggest a time I heard before. Is someone too lazy to take the kids out to the park? Is someone too lazy to buy groceries for dinner? In general, "very lazy to do something" makes sense because I know what you mean to say. Then again if a baby said "Wawa" I know he means water, but as he gets older he should stop saying "Wawa" and use the right word. Maybe that's why you ask because it sounds wrong even though the idea is understood.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).